# Is there any proof for this convergence conjecture?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\left\{u_i\right\}_{i=1}^m$ be a sequence of real vectors, i.e. $u_i\in R^n, 1\le i\le m $ such that $\sum_{i=1}^m u_i u_i^T$ is a positive definite matrix. Define:

$$K_m:=\left(\sum_{i=1}^m u_i u_i^T\right)^{-1}u_m$$

Show that $\left\| K_m\right\| $ tends to zero as $m\longrightarrow \infty$.

**Edit-** I have not been able to find a counter-example. So I assumed that this can be proved. Also it is not something I totally made up. The result can be used to present another proof for the convergence of a well-known algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

This is an incomplete proof (hence, not a proof), but it might be better than nothing for a start.

Let $S_m=\sum_{i=1}^m u_i u_i^\top$. Then $||K_m||\leq ||S_m||^{-1} ||u_m||$.

If the sequence $(||u_m||)$ converges to 0, then so does $||K_m||$ because $||S_m||\neq 0$.

Otherwise, there exist a bound $\epsilon$ such that $\forall i, \ ||u_i||>\epsilon$. The question is to prove whether or not this implies $\lim S_n = \infty$. If so, the conjecture is correct. I am stuck because $\sum_{i=1}^m||u_i u_i||^\top \geq m \epsilon^2$ does not imply that $S_m$ diverges, a priori.